# Why isn't the "remember me" checkbox in login forms enabled by default?

Tags: forms, login, privacy

On the majority of sites, a "remember me" checkbox on login forms is not selected by default. Most users would like to stay logged in after login. It annoys users each time to have to enter username and password just because they forget to check that checkbox.

**Why not just enable the "remember me" checkbox by default?**

If the user does not want to be remembered, he can just uncheck the checkbox.

**Update**: "remember me" checkbox in Gmail login forms is not selected by default, but if the user logs in and enables it, this choice is saved to cookies and the checkbox will be enabled by default at the next login.

**Update 2**: by [37signals](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/1920-has-the-time-come-to-kill-the-remember-me):

> Has the time come to kill the “Remember me” check box and just assume that people using shared computers will simply logout?

**Update 3**: I wrote a **[WordPress plugin which enables "remember me" by default](https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-to-use/)**. So you may use it if you want to.

**Update 4**:  "remember me" is enabled by default on [Basecamp login page](https://launchpad.37signals.com/basecamp).

**Update 5**:  "remember me" is enabled by default on [WordPress.com login page](https://wordpress.com/wp-login.php).

[image: enable remember-me by default]

Comment: An interesting discussion I ran across while looking into substantial evidence for this question: http://www.usabilitypost.com/2009/10/05/remember-me/

Comment: @GotDibbs +1, thanks for comment, your post is great. Quote: "check the “Remember me” box by default. This is exactly what Google is doing." - After Google in a few years everyone will do the same. Users should get used for new things. Google solve the problem of "forget to logout" perfectly: they give ability for user to "sign out all other sessions" on ther computers where user is logged in at the moment. If something works - it stays. Enabled "rem me" by default is pretty useful.

Comment: You're being quite subjective with your question, it sounds like you've made up your mind and are just looking for someone to validate it rather than genuinely wanting an actual answer. Points such as *"It annoys users each time to enter username and password just because user forget to check "remember me" checkbox"* may not be factually correct, you're just assuming this to be the case.

Comment: @GotDibbs as [Myrddin Emrys said](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/20924/why-remember-me-checkbox-in-login-forms-is-not-enabled-by-default#comment29097_20926): "If you visit Google and log in for the first time, the 'Stay signed in' checkbox is disabled. If you choose to enable it, then it remembers your preference and stays checked the next time you visit."
I checked it and it is true: **Google offers "rem me" disabled by default** and saves users choice to cookie.

Comment: @ Jon W: "it sounds like you've made up your mind and are just looking for someone to validate it" - could be. Is it bad?
I heard some interesting answers here and I am pretty satisfied of them and even if some of them does not support mine point of view.

Comment: @JonW: I am trying to make login form more easy for users on my sites and I decide to enable "rem me" by default and I am trying to find bad effects of it. I tried to enable "rem me" by default for a few days on one site and it does not created problems for users. But it was more easy for users because they was already logged in for the second visit.

Comment: @webvitaly you keep stating in your comments on the answers to this post that users prefer to stay logged in, but where is your *evidence* that this is the case? Making assumptions **especially** when they concern user security is a very dangerous position to take.

Comment: @JonW: ok, lets try to imagine something :) What if the developers, who developed first login forms never invented "rem me" checkbox? What if Google or facebook will remove this checkbox? Would it be problem for you? IMHO after some time of using without "rem me" you would think that it is not needed at all.
I saw many different options in login forms: "rem my computer", "rem me for 1 month", "rem my IP" and combination of few of them. It looks like it is useful for users to have many options but many options spend time for decision and sometime creates confusion or frustration.

Comment: @webvitaly the issue is not about what I think (nor what any individual person thinks) but what provides the best overall experience and benefit for users *as a whole*.

Comment: it strikes me that logically the kind of person who forgets to untick a remember me box would probably also be the kind of person who forgets to logout.

I don't think these days it would be the epic problem it would have been once upon a time- public computers are getting rarer whilst private devices are the norm- but opting out is still likely to create more problems than opting in

Comment: Be interesting to get an answer that relates to apps on mobile devices too. You don't necessarily get the option to 'remember me' on app login form. the app (take Facebook for example) will keep that user logged in even if the app is closed down an reopened. you have to find the logout button in the app if you want the details cleared. Any reflection on this or was this question related solely to websites?

Comment: @DaveHaigh Good point. This question was asked in 2012 and I had no phones in mind then.

Answer (score 45):

If you think about it, clearly, and logically the default value must be **"off"**. This can be proven if you look at the use cases of the sign in life cycle.

Let me explain, by comparing the browsing behavior of two different types of users. **User #A** will be one who likes remember me disabled, and **User #B** likes to have it enabled. Let's compare what happens to both users given the two possible default values "on" and "off". NOTE: I'm talking about the risks of setting a default value.

**Default for Remember Me is "off"**

**User #A** when going to the website is presented with the log in screen. They enter their username/password and click the sign in button. They are granted access, but when they close the browser their session is ended. They will be prompted again for their password next time they visit, and this is good for this user.

**User #B** when going to the website it's the same thing. They enter their username/password and click sign in button (they forget to click "remember me"). When they leave, they are signed out. This is not "liked" by the user but there is no security problem.

**Default for Remember Me is "on"**

**User #A** goes to the website, enters their username/password and clicks the sign in button. Their session becomes permanent. The next time someone visits from that computer they will be granted access. *This is not liked by this user, and is a security problem.*

**User #B** goes to the website, enters their username/password and clicks the sign in button. Their session becomes permanent. *This is accepted by the user, they don't mind the security risk*

**Result**

It's clear, that when remember me is on. Both use cases present a security problem when the user fails to change the state of the "remember me" check box. It doesn't really matter that User #B doesn't mind that the risk is there.

The point here is that when the default is "off", should both users login with out changing the value then there is *no security risk*.

***Further more, now that many third-party websites are using open authentication. Users who leave themselves logged into Facebook/Google/Yahoo/Twitter are also granting access to thousands of other websites that use oAuth services for registration and authentication.***

If someone gains access to your Facebook account, then they can go to the Apps section and gain access to all the other websites you've used Facebook to sign into. The same for Google, Twitter, GMail, etc.. etc..

How do you feel about auto remembering now? :)

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I could agree with you about enabled "rem me" by default on popular sites (facebook, google) or secured (PayPal, Ebay). And what about smaller sites? IMHO there is no big risk or security problems to leave "rem me" enabled by default.

Comment: @webvitaly: really? Don't assume security isn't a problem because the information is trivial. I don't have anything to hide, yet I don't want just anybody to be able to read stuff that is addressed to or written by me (including the old-fashioned postman).

Comment: @webvitaly: sounds like what you want is "late authentication" where a user's session can be restored without prompting for a password (remember me). That user can use the website as the previous user, but the moment they attempt to perform a risky action (delete, edit, create) then their ID can be authenticated by prompting for a password. Example, you can log into a message board as yourself without being prompted, but the first time you try to post something it asks for your password, or when you try to read private messages. Maybe posting doesn't required it, but private messages do.

Comment: @webvitaly Even if there wasn't a risk for smaller websites, you now lack standard behavior across websites. The user now has to focus to determine if this is one of those sites that has it defaulted or doesn't. This just creates confusion. One method across all sites is better for user experience in this case, at least in my opinion.

Comment: @FrankB "If I'd asked my customers what they wanted, they'd have said a faster horse. - Henry Ford"
Most part of users does not care about what is set by default, only advanced users does. But almost everyone is annoyed to enter username and password next time while logging in. So it would be better for more part of users to have "remember me" enabled by default.

Comment: @webvitaly in the year this question was ask things have changed. It's now become standard for browsers like Chrome/Firefox to prompt the user to save their passwords. This gives control to the user, and next time they visit the fields are pre-populated. I find this approach better.

Comment: @webvitaly. I think you're guilty of what you're accusing me of. It's annoying for you to enter your username and password each time you go to a site, but do you have any evidence that this is the case with the majority of users? And if most users don't care what is set by default, it's all the more important that we are careful with what we set by default since security now falls back to us since the users don't care. So we should give them the safest setting (in this case uncheck the remember me) instead of default to a dangerous setting.

Comment: Also, opt-in by default is a bad choice if you want your service to [comply with European law](http://www.forbes.com/sites/timworstall/2013/01/10/the-eu-warns-tech-firms-opt-out-is-no-longer-good-enough/).

Comment: @FrankB I'll leave one link instead of hundred words :)
https://launchpad.37signals.com/basecamp

Answer (score 16):

It should be an opt in.

What happens if you log in from an Internet Cafe or your mate's laptop and forget to sign out properly?

The next person who uses that machine (either a random person of the street or your mate) will be able to log into your account on that site. Now, while that might not be an issue for IMDb or Code Project, it would be a big deal if it were Amazon or your bank.

Comment: Ooh, I forgot about public computers. Good catch.

Comment: To ChrisF: what is the average percentage of your logins when you clicked remember me? 80, or more, or less? 
Ok, if the site is very secured (PayPal or Amazon) than "remember me" could be disabled by default. But in all other cases 80% of the users should click "remember me" checkbox because a few people sometime uses friend's laptops. IMHO it does not worth it.
Google solve this problem perfectly: they give ability for user to "sign out all other sessions" on ther computers where you are logged in.

Comment: @webvitaly - I don't know what % of sites I stay logged in on. However, I don't tend to log in from public computers either.

Comment: "I don't know what % of sites I stay logged in on" - I will try to guess, most of them. :)
"I don't tend to log in from public computers either" - awesome, you can just disable "rem me" checkbox and that's it. Logins on public or other's computers is the minority. So why does majority should click this checkbox? :)

Comment: @webvitaly - I don't think it's most of them, but the ones I have chosen to remain logged in on have all been a concious decision.

Comment: I made one experiment on one site:
few days "rem me" was disabled and majority of users (80%) leave it disabled. Then during next few days I enabled "rem me" by default and guess what? 80% of users left "rem me" enabled.
It means, that most part of users does not click that checkbox and users like decitions to be made for them.
And, as I already said, it annoys users each time to enter username and password just because user forget to check "remember me" checkbox.

Comment: @webvitaly - I never choose 'remember me' on 100% of the sites that I use.  It annoys me, a web user, to revisit a website, after closing down all browsers, to discover I'm still logged in. For me, that's one less reason to trust the owners of the website.

Comment: @JW. "I never choose 'remember me' on 100% of the sites that I use." - so, as I understand, you choose "rem me" on about 80% of sites you are visit. So, what is better: to check "rem me" in 80% or uncheck "rem me" on 20%? 
P.S. I agree, than on bank sites or paypal-like sites "rem me" should be disabled by default.

Comment: @webvitaly Nope. I never choose "rem me" on any site I visit.

Comment: @JW. So you each time login to facebook and it does not annoy you? :)

Comment: @webvitaly No, it does not annoy me. I have got used to the process of logging-in to sites. It acts like a 'time-sapping guard'. Thus, I limit my access to FB to a few minutes once or twice a day. Also I never store passwords on my PC.  I do not use ftp and I am used to using a SSH passphrase each time I upload a file to my web server. In short, if someone stole my computer, there is very little they can do to steal my identity and it makes me much more aware of security than most people.

Comment: @webvitaly I should add that, so far in my lifetime: I have had my house burgled 4 times (including one fight with a burglar) and have lost 3 mobile phones. So, I assume the worst and treat my prersonal devices like I would treat a shared device. I realise that I am odd because I am overly cautious. If IT workers/designers are lax about their personal security, they are likely to be lax about work security. Hence, all those stories about data breaches on big websites are not really surprising.

Comment: @JW. you are very unlucky guy. But even if I would be on your place I would still check "rem me" on my own devices. After losing some device, I would just change my passwords on main sites which I am using and that's it. IMHO it is easier to change passwords once than enter it each time. 
p.s. imho alarm system or hidden cameras could help you in future.

Answer (score 11):

### It should be disabled by default.

- User **A** will be one who likes 'remember me' disabled, and
- User **B** likes to have it enabled.

**A** logs-in far more often than **B** because they prefer not to be remembered.

If "remember me" checkbox is enabled by default, **A** has to untick that box each time they log-in, and that's just a pain.

### The Proof

We can approach this like a utilitarian and tally up the pain caused in each scenario.

Let's say both users visit the site once per day.

### If "remember me" checkbox is enabled by default:

Over a 10 day period,

- User **A** will log in ten times AND **suffer the pain of unticking the checkbox ten times**.
- User **B** will log in once.

### If "remember me" checkbox is disabled by default:

Over a 10 day period,

- User **A** will log in **ten times** (as they expect).
- User **B** will log in once AND **suffer the pain of ticking the checkbox, just, once**

---

So, the scenario causing the minimum pain is when "remember me" checkbox is disabled by default.

Comment: On a related note, adding an additional step to "remember me", such as asking the user to name the present computer, would only represent a tiny burden and could allow users to see what machines they're logged in on, and log off of any machines they no longer control.

Answer (score 6):

Privacy. Opt-in vs opt-out. While I do usually choose to have a site remember me, there are many people who get upset or creeped out by a site that automatically knows who they are when they return. In general all privacy related activities should be opt-in because of this.

In addition, the 'Remember me' box is so short and clear that users will see it and understand it even though they only skim pages and almost never read much text.

Comment: "there are many people who get upset or creeped out by a site that automatically knows who they are when they return" - very strange users :)
I have published some comments for prev answer and there are some related to your answer. You may check them, maybe you have something to add.

Comment: Try working with older users sometimes, or those new to the Internet; you will find some odd reactions at times. Then look at the prevalence of plugins that block all cookies. Two ends of the spectrum (unsavvy and very savvy) who both do not want a site to remember them.

Comment: Google works with older users too, but "rem me" checkbox in their login forms is enabled by default. And users love it and this is pretty useful.

Comment: You are incorrect sir. If you visit Google and log in for the first time, the 'Stay signed in' checkbox is **disabled**. If you choose to enable it, then it remembers your preference and stays checked the next time you visit. Try visiting their site from a fresh browser with no cookies and you will see this. Google uses opt-in as well.

Comment: +1, Yes, you are right, "rem me" is disabled by default for the first time and user's choice about this checkbox saved to cookies. Ok, so Google offers "rem me" disabled and saves users choice. Does this solve problem with public computers? If prev user checked "rem me" checkbox and will logout, so the next user will see "rem me" enabled too. IMHO, majority of users would rather have "rem me" enabled by dafault and they could uncheck it if they want to.

Comment: As soon as you manually log out, 'Remember me' defaults to off again.

Comment: the state of "rem me" checkbox in Google login form is setted to the state which user made. And if user logged in with enabled "rem me", than after logout - "rem me" will be enabled.

Answer (score 2):

There are two cases for "Remember me"  or another check box "keep me signed in" functionality:

**Case I**: When user is using a personal computer / workstation or mobile device , they often opt for **remember me** option or **keep me signed** in option to save time for repeated login or use. That's common, most of us would not like to reenter same and same credentials for multiple websites or apps that we use daily.

**Case II**: When we use shared systems with in family or at any Cyber Cafe, we would not like to opt for remember me feature. That's generic thing.

What should be the default status of Remember Me check box?

In my opinion, it depends on the type of service or app being used. For example, for social networking sites / apps like Facebook , Twitter, etc user maximum user would choose Remember me  for frequent login. But for Apps or Services like a Banking app, funds transfer, Book keeping , commercial services, etc maximum user would not prefer remember me functionality and most of the service provider do not even offer this feature.

I hope you find it useful.

Regards

Bhaumik

Answer (score 1):

I've never understood that checkbox. It isn't at the right place (how can you remember me if you don't know who I am?). After the user has signed in for the first time on a particular computer, show an unobstrusive popup asking if the credentials should be remembered *on that specific computer*.

Answer (score 1):

This opt-in has more to do with ethics. You are creating a cookie on the user's computer; cookies are generally harmless but they're still technically invasive. Thus, you make the user grant permission via checking the checkbox.

Newsletter signups on the web tend to be opt-out, and I think they should be opt-in, but the potential consequences aren't as bad as with login forms.

FYI I never use the Remember Me feature online.

Answer (score 0):

The logic in the answers on this page are all correct, but there is something people are not considering which may change the answer depending on the type of product.

1. 95% of the time you are accessing a website from a device you trust, so the odds are that this is what is best for the user
2. even when it is best for the user, many users will forget to the check the box, or not understand it's purpose, or not care to think about it since they are in a rush - often people don't change default settings
3. the next time they try to use your site (imagine them on mobile, at a party - where typing/remembering emails/passwords is challenging) you have presented them with a hurdle to using it, and they may just give up and not use it at all right then
4. in this case you have created a bad experience for most of your users, by choosing the wrong default setting
5. some websites have a sign in state that still prompts you for additional verification (usually two factor authentication) when you are doing especially sensitive actions

So the argument here is that you may want to encourage this behavior for your users so they will have a better experience with your product, if you feel it outweighs the security risk for the smaller percentage of users on public or shared computers.

I've never seen any research on this question (of users who should enable 'remember me' how many actually do it and when?) but it wouldn't surprise if me if something like 50% of users don't use that setting correctly on the first 3 sign ins.

The counter argument is that even if they mess it up the first few times, they will eventually get it and they only need to get it right once per device (assuming you are not resetting all session periodically etc).  However, this can still be 2-3 signins per device or something before they get it all set up correctly on their laptop, mobile, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Funny, I always default the remember me checkbox to off, but I do it in defense of the site owner.  My logic works like this...

A user account gets accessed by another unauthorized user and real substantive damage is done to the owner of the account.  This damage can take many forms, including theft of a credit balance on the site, the unauthorized sale of assets through the site, or just the release of confidential information (the user's medical records, emails, etc) into general public knowledge.

Now imagine that the scale of the damage is large enough to warrant legal action and the victim sues the site owner.  Even with beautifully written terms-of-use and user-access-agreement documents integrated into the site's registration process, even with if you require strong passwords and expire passwords, wouldn't you want to be able to tell a judge that the site was designed with user's security as its primary concern?

The remember-me checkbox is the single most visible expression of a site's attitude towards user security.  Defaulting it to off declares quite publically that you value a user's safety more than their convenience.