# Is two-field confirmation for emails or passwords user-friendly?

Tags: email, password, confirmation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why should we ask the password twice during registration?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/20953/why-should-we-ask-the-password-twice-during-registration)

It is a very common pattern to require a user to enter things like an email address, or - more importantly - a not-visible password twice as a way to reduce the risk of errors when entering the new password.

I understand the reason why this seems necessary.

But it feels kind of like unnecessary work for the user. Are there better ways to do this?