# Repeat password field necessary in a signup page?

Tags: usability, forms, interaction-design, user-expectation, login

Possible Duplicate: Why should we ask the password twice during registration? When designing a new and simplified signup page I got into an argument with a colleague about the necessity of the "repeat password" field. We designed the signup process in such a way that the ...

Comment: The question seems unfinished... do you have more information to add?...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why should we ask the password twice during registration?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/20953/why-should-we-ask-the-password-twice-during-registration)

Answer (score 0):

The best option would be to go with the single password field, but ONLY if these are both applicable:

- Your "forgot password" functionality is a smooth process. It should be a quick and easy process that makes resetting the password can happen effortlessly.
- You give the user the option, with a checkbox or something, to make the password entry visible. Don't set this as the default for security reasons, but give the user the option to make sure they entered their password correctly before submission.